# cdn is working fine but enqueue is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to include a `jquery` library in my code and I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This works perfectly fine and I got what I needed but then I try to enqueue wordpress's preloaded `jquery` library like this:

```
function my_switchbutton_function(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_switchbutton_function');
```

But this is not working I don't know why...I need to enqueue style too ?
versioning is same `1.11.4` in both cdn and preloaded js.

Is there any other script too that I need to enqueue ?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273986/correct-way-to-enqueue-jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

You need to define js filepath in the function

Example:

```
<?php

function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/js/amazing_script.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

Replace get_template_directory_uri with get_stylesheet_directory_uri if you are using child theme and your file path is in child theme

Comment: but i am using this in my plugin file....and what i am trying to do is enqueue script that wordpress defined it already .. with my code its loaded perfectly but don't know what i missed

Comment: I am Not sure what you mean by already defined script but you can define js path from plugin by wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ) );

Comment: predefined means jquery library that wordpress already added in wp-includes > script-loader.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myjs'); // add at front side
       add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myjs'); // to add at admin side

       function myjs() {
         wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js', array(), '3', true);
        }
```

Comment: true this will work but **1).** i want to enqueue this script on back-end so i have to use admin_enqueue_scripts **2).** i have to use predefined wordpress jquery library. as i want to upload this plugin on wordpress they said you have to use predefined jq library

Comment: just change wp_enque_scripts with admin_enqueue_scripts it will work

Comment: i know this will work but wordpress days **Your plugin has included (or called it remotely, probably from Google or jquery.com) your own copy of a javascript file that WordPress already includes.** and **DO NOT include your own copy of javascript files that are already included in WordPress Core**,**DO NOT make remote calls to javascript files that are already included in WordPress Core**

Comment: Here you need to download this file and save that in your plugin directory give the proper path using plugin dir function and submit your plugin this comment will not be come from wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to solve your Question

```
<?php
function twentyseventeen_child_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyseventeen_child_enqueue_scripts');
?>
```